# Customize xaxis in multiple charts

Tags: highcharts

I needed to individually customize each xaxis charts, name, type etc. ...

eg:

```
dataObj.data1 = [5,8,9,6,7,4,5,6,3,2];//...column  (mm) eg
dataObj.data2 = [2,5,9,6,3,5,4,1,7,5]; //...area  (ºC) eg
dataObj.data3 = [4,5,8,9,6,3,5,7,4,2]; //...spiline  (hpa) eg
dataObj.data4 = [3,6,9,8,5,2,1,4,7,8];
dataObj.data5 = [1,2,4,5,7,8,9,3,6,4];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/XQu8E/11/

is that possible?

thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried?  It took me 30 seconds of effort:  http://jsfiddle.net/XQu8E/27/

Comment: thank you very much, believe it or not I've tried hundreds of times, now will try to format each series, I hope so.

Comment: Are you looking to actually use that chart swapping technique, or do you just need to set up different charts with different options?  And are you looking to customize the y axis labels for each chart, or just the title for the y axis?

Comment: I need to set up different charts with different option and customize the y axis labels for each chart,

costing me a lot of work because I just understood ways of operation chart, and the examples are not fit my needs

eg


tooltip: {
     formatter: function () {
              return '<b> Hours: </ b>' + this.x +
                     '<br/> <b> Model: </ b>' + this.series.name +
                     '<br/> <b> Percent: </ b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat (this.y, 0, '.') + '%';
         }
     }

I need this, but independent for each graph

Comment: But what is wrong with example created by Mark, because in his solution, you destroy chart and can configure each aspect of new chart

Comment: Hello Sebastion, thanks

It's all correct and perfect, but I can not see how to customize each chart individually. I always support them in the examples for my personal settings (very useful jlbriggs examples), but in this case I have not found anything, but I think'm not too far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution in this other example:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/jlbriggs/TRd7f/